# Dismiss view controller from unwind segue

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift2

I have 3 view controllers. I can go from A to B, then from B to C. I've made an unwind segue from B to A. When it's performed, I can see that view controller B has been deallocated, and VC A appears on screen. 
To make it I added next code to VC A and made unwind segue on button in VC B.

```
@IBAction func unvindSegueToMenu(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {}
```

However, when I go to VC C (from B) I want to perform unwind Segue from VC C to A. To do that I put next code to VC B class.

```
@IBAction func unvindSegueToMainMenu(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
}
```

After I press button in VC C, it shows me VC A as I want, but in Allocation Summary I can see that VC B has not been deallocated.
What is my mistake and how can I deallocate it?

Comment: why do you need to put "unvindSegueToMenu:" implemention in B ? it should be in A, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you made something wrong in your code.
i tested and i can see clearly that **VC B is deallocated** after performing the unwind segue.

First be sure that you made it right. *(for example the performed method of the unwind segue should be implemented in the destination VC)*

Also you can check after performing the unwind how many viewControllers you have in the navigationController..in your case should be 2 , but if you do it in the right way it will be only one.

Comment: Something is definitely wrong, I removed method to A, and it shows VC A as I want, but VC B is still allocated.

Comment: I found a mistake. In my VC C I use SKView to Present SKScene, before I perform unwind segue I should use .removeAllChildren() method on my SKScene.